# GROUP BY with the most recent elements

Tags: mysql, sql

Generally we use SELECT MAX(datetime) with GROUP BY(page_ID) to get the most recent pages but I don't understand why it doesn't work here.

My following query should only select rows ID 75 and 77 but its selects 75 and 76 :
[image]

```
SELECT ru.page_ID AS id, 
    pFrom.name AS name,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ru.rating_time) AS action_date,                          
    ru.current_rank AS current_rank,        
    MAX(ru.rating_time)                     
FROM ranks_update ru
INNER JOIN pages pFrom
    ON ru.page_ID = pFrom.page_ID
WHERE ru.ranking_ID = :id_rk
    AND ru.page_ID IN ( ** subquery 1 **)
    AND ru.rating_time >= ( ** subquery  2 **)                      
GROUP BY ru.page_ID                             
ORDER BY ru.current_sum_vote DESC
```

Comment: It's because MySQL lets you do evil things.

Comment: What value are you passing to id_rk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ru.page_ID AS id, 
    pFrom.name AS name,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ru.rating_time) AS action_date,                          
    ru.current_rank AS current_rank,        
    rum.MaxDate
from ranks_update ru
inner join(
    select page_ID, MAX(rating_time) as MaxDate
    from ranks_update
    WHERE ranking_ID = :id_rk
        AND page_ID IN ( ** subquery 1 **)
        AND rating_time >= ( ** subquery  2 **)   
    group by page_ID
) rum on ru.page_ID = rum.page_ID and ru.rating_time = rum.MaxDate
inner join pages pFrom on ru.page_ID = pFrom.page_ID
ORDER BY ru.current_sum_vote DESC
```

Comment: You succeeded in resolve the problem, can you explain me why a simple SELECT MAX(datetime) with GROUP BY didn't work ?

Comment: Your error was in returning columns that were neither grouped nor aggregated in a `GROUP BY` query. This is something MySQL lets you do that almost any other dbms will not, because the values you get back are indeterminate, and thus not usually useful.

Answer (score 0):

A contributory factor will be MySQL's quirky interpretation of `GROUP BY`. In standard SQL you have to specify all non aggregated columns (eg: `GROUP BY ru.page_ID, pFrom.name, ru.currentRank, ru.current_sum_vote`). MySQL will allow you not to do that, but its behaviour is undefined and quite possibly random. If you write standard SQL, you'll get predictable results.

Comment: it's group by `page_ID`, not `ID`

Comment: "2012-10-02 01:50:57" is later than "2012-10-02 02:50:57" ? You must have read too fast...

Comment: @Anon Ah. They're upside down :)